# Is "если есть" a kind of tautology?

Tags: словоупотребление, выражения, clauses, conditional, subordinate-clause

Wiktionary says that the word **если** ("if") originated from **есть ли**  (literally "whether is"):

> Происходит от стар. естьли (ещё у Карамзина), ср.: укр. єсли, польск. jeśli, др.-польск. jestli, чешск. jestli и т. д. Из jestь li. ([Link](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8))

I also found in Google that **есть ли** (written as two separate words or as a single word) was routinely used in old Russian texts to express **if**:

> (1) **Естьли** въ ариѳметикѣ изъ двухъ данныхъ чиселъ третіе слѣдуетъ непрекословно, то и въ семъ происшествіи слѣдствіе было необходимо.
>
> (2) А **есть ли** бъ Карпъ или Сидоръ названъ былъ, такъ тогда навѣдаться можно объ нихъ и отъ нихъ.
>
> (3) Могъ ли бъ я вѣрить, **есть ли** бъ я не видѣлъ, кто меня нынѣ толь возненавидѣлъ.

In Sentences (1)-(3) **есть ли** does precisely the same thing as **если** does in modern Russian.

Moreover, I also found numerous examples of using **есть ли** to express **if** in modern Russian:

> (4) В идеале, хотелось бы узнать, существует ли закон, обязывающий физическое лицо платить НДФЛ от переводов полученных от юр. лиц. И **есть ли** есть, то где можно почитать про это и проверить какие там есть исключения. ([Source](https://pravoved.ru/question/2312885))
>
> (5) **Есть ли** есть желание, Вы можете передать эти вопросы рекрутеру и попросить ответить на эти вопросы через email. ([Source](https://habr.com/ru/post/289050/))
>
> (6) Есть ли в ваших магазинах духи Legacy Cristiano Ronaldo? И **есть ли** есть подскажите стоимость. ([Source](http://www.rivegauche.ru/faq/question/est-li-v-vashih-magazinah-duhi-legacy-cristiano-ronaldo-i-est-li-est-podskazhite-0))

My question is this: Given that **если** already contains **есть**, is **если есть** a kind of repetition like **буде будет** or **масло масляное**? In other words, is using **если есть** somewhat hilarious or disrespectful to the history of the Russian language, and should I therefore avoid using **если есть**?

Comment: A modern speaker doesn't perceive Если as containing есть + ли. Cnf Спасибо (thanks) etymologically contains спаси+бог (save God), but a modern speaker doesn't mean God when using спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not at all. People use **если есть** all the time, and avoiding it would be as gratuitously pedantic as avoiding **был бы**. The connection is no longer felt, and the `есть ли` of your examples 4–6 is a spelling mistake despite being etymologically correct.

Comment: Are you really sure that examples 4-6 are spelling mistakes and not just a dialect in which "есть ли" as "if" survived? Look what I found in the Internet: https://www.rusfootball.info/pliga/1146531853-magomed-adiev-ahmat-est-li-est-hot-maleyshiy-shans-to-ya-ostanus-v-anzhi.html Look at the title(!) of this article. The title is: *Магомед Адиев: "Ахмат"? **Есть ли** есть хоть малейший шанс, то я останусь в "Анжи"*. How could a spelling mistake like that be made in a title?

Comment: Your answer really confused me. If someone made a spelling mistake, either he simply pressed a wrong button because he ''missed'' a target with his finger, or he did not know how to write the word correctly. But you cannot type **есть ли есть** if you intend to type **если есть**. You can type, for example, **есаи есть** or smth like that, but you cannot hit the keys **т** and **ь** consecutively if it is not your intent. It is like typing "bull" and saying it was a series of spelling mistakes in "cow."

Comment: And if a person believes that **есть ли** is a valid form of **если**, and if it is really not, then how come he wasn't taught properly at school? **Если** is a fundamental word. How could his Russian teacher ignore the wrong spelling?

Comment: I hope you get my point. What have you to say to that?

Comment: @Mitsuko As I was explained, a "wrong button" mistake is called something else, a "typo". Those are specifically not-knowing-how-it's-spelt mistakes, the "their/they're" kind — which of course can be made accidentally in a hurry too. And yes, there's a mistake in that RusFootball title, which the proofreader, if they have one, didn't catch. What can I say, some people didn't pay attention in school; some type faster than they think, as it were; one way or another, it's wrong.

Comment: @Mitsuko And by "wrong" I, being rather anti-prescriptivist, mean this: no plurality of opinion presently exists on how you spell **если**. Those who tend to correct people's spelling will correct `есть ли`. Those who accept such corrections will correct themselves, maybe after consulting a dictionary. Those who don't care will continue spelling it how they like *because they don't care* (as is their right, I should add, being anti-prescriptivist and all — unless spelling according to norm is in their job description) — but not *because they believe differently* about how it shold be spelt.

Comment: Please type the exact phrase "есть ли есть" in quotation marks in Google and have a look at the results. In about a half them,  "есть ли" means "if." And the number of results is about 500,000. Please check yourself. Isn't it too much for a spelling mistake? How could you comment such a great number of results?

Comment: Are many Russians THAT ignorant of the correct spelling of this fundamental word, or what? :)

Comment: @Mitsuko It is a lot for a spelling mistake, but it's also not the actual number of matches. Google can be weird like that. Yes, I got "About 488,000 results" on page one, but try going to page 6 or further and see what happens.

Comment: Ohhhh indeed. Google tricked me. The actual number is about 100.

Comment: I now got curious about another thing: How do people end up making this spelling mistake? To make a spelling mistake, you must somehow get a wrong idea about how to spell the word. How could these people think that **если** is spelt with **т**? As I understand, **если** is pronounced as **если**, exactly as written. There is no **т** sound there. How on earth could these people think that **т** is needed? Where could they hear or see **т** in **если**? Did they read old Russian texts too much, or what? Or do people sometimes pronounce **т** in **если** in some Russian dialects?

Comment: they're just not very literate people. they probably didn't read much. I've seen many similar mistakes, for example: "Не навящево" instead of "ненавязчиво", etc.

Comment: @Mitsuko Aah, so that's why. The /т/ inside the clusters `-стл-` and `-стн-` is silent. **Местный** is pronounced [месный], etc. Hypercorrection may cause people to insert extra /т/'s where they don't belong (e.g. **взрослый** — misspelt as "взростлый", it would be pronouonced the same).

Comment: wow, this really explains everything! Now I even understand how **есть ли** became **если**: The sound **т** simply got silent, just like in **местный**, and then it was decided that the word has to be written just as it is pronounced - without **т**. And now some people sometimes accidentally add **т** just because of the habit to insert **т** between **с** and **л**.

Comment: そっか :) The puzzle has been solved :)

Answer (score 1):

No, for russian speaker it hears *if is* or *if eat* dont forget to be | eat = есть so there is also lexem ambigity here, russian is so weird.

P.S. Do not judge modern russian by reading old one with ѣ whatever